# formula consolidate nonempty values over same row range for multiple sequential rows in excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula-based answer here if possible. I'll give a specific example but to be clear, I'm intending to use this solution in a more complex setting (i.e., will work if i add more sheets).

suppose I'm in a workbook with four sheets : [summary], [a], [b], [c] in that order.

!$A$2:$A$6 of each sheet [a],[b],[c] are filled with formulae that either produce empty values ("") or desired information (non-empty text). If it helps, !$A$1 of each sheet [a],[b],[c] gives a count for how many of those five cells are non-empty.

```
[a]!$A$2:$A$6 = "", "red", "truck", "", "train"
[a]!$A$1 = 3
[b]!$A$2:$A$6 = "", "", "", "ball", ""
[b]!$A$1 = 1
[c]!$A$2:$A$6 = "pterodactyl", "", "", "", "bills"
[c]!$A$1 = 2
```

on [summary] I want to use a formula or series of formulae to produce in a single column, with no empty values, all of the non-empty values from the specified range in [a],[b],[c]. order isn't important to me but for example :

```
[summary]!$A$1:$A$6 = "red", "truck", "train", "ball", "pterodactyl", "bills"
```

how would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked around with Scott's formula and got it a little more dynamic. Not sure if suits your needs but here goes.

**Helper Table**

- Each header is the name of the sheet in question. This is required for the INDIRECT
- `=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT(A$1&"!A:A"),AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(INDIRECT(A$1&"!$A$2:$A$6"))/(INDIRECT(A$1&"!$A$2:$A$6")<>""),ROW(1:1))),"")`
- Once the formula has been entered in R1C1 of the table, it can be dragged across

**Helper Column**

- `{=INDEX(CHOOSE(N(IF({1},COLUMN(Table2[#Headers]))),Table2[a],Table2[b],Table2[c]),
  MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,ROWS(Table2))+1,
  MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,COLUMNS(Table2))+1)}`
- You will have to manually adjust the CHOOSE function to add more Table columns
- This is an Array formula dragged down for until you reach ROWS(Table2) * COLUMNS(Table2)
- For simplicity sake, I turned this into a named range called List1

**Final Column**

- `{=IFERROR(INDEX(List1,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(List1)-1/(List1<>""),ROW(1:1))),"")}`
- This is an Array formula dragged down

[image]

Comment: Oh, and VBA would have probably been a much simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX AGGREGATE with IFERROR to move to the next page as the list runs out.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(a!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(a!$A$2:$A$6)/(a!$A$2:$A$6<>""),ROW(1:1))),INDEX(b!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(b!$A$2:$A$6)/(b!$A$2:$A$6<>""),ROW(1:1)-a!$A$1))),INDEX('c'!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW('c'!$A$2:$A$6)/('c'!$A$2:$A$6<>""),ROW(1:1)-(a!$A$1+b!$A$1))))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a more compact way to do this? The example has three sheets with data but for my purposes there will be a variable number (possibly dozens or more) of sheets with data

Comment: Not without vba, I have been trying to make it dynamic, but none will do it any better.